# JavaScript - Sum/merge multiple objects in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I would like to sum up two objects into one total object and get a percent change of the two values (add then divide by # of values). I'm having some issues applying this logic. The data is dynamic so there could be more than two objects in the same array.

My preferred method is JavaScript but jQuery is perfectly fine as well if it's simpler! Below is an example and here is a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4z63cwhz/4/

Response Data:

```
$scope.data = [
       {
          "July":{
             "params":{
                "frequency":"Monthly",
                "category":"Overview",
                "year":"2015",
                "month":"July"
             },
             "subcategory":{
                "us total":{
                   "interaction rate":0.51,
                   "digital interaction rate":8.33,
                   "impressions":500,
                   "interactions":256
                },
                "discover me":{
                   "digital u.s. discover site sessions":50
                },
                "me com":{
                   "total me.com site sessions":50
                }
             },
             "action":"new"
          },
          "August":{
             "params":{
                "frequency":"Monthly",
                "category":"Overview",
                "year":"2015",
                "month":"August"
             },
             "subcategory":{
                "us total":{
                   "interaction rate":0.51,
                   "digital interaction rate":8.33,
                   "impressions":500,
                   "interactions":256
                },
                "discover me":{
                   "digital u.s. discover site sessions":50
                },
                "me com":{
                   "total me.com site sessions":50
                }
             },
             "action":"new"
          }
       }
    ]
```

JS:

```
$scope.calculate = function(){
        var sumObj = {};


        var local = $scope.data;
        for(var i in local){
            var obj = local[i];
            for(var i2 in obj){
                for(var i3 in obj[i2].subcategory){
                    //do the calculation here.
                    console.log(i3);

                }
            }

        }
    };
```

The `sumObj` I was hoping to get would be similar to below:

```
{
     "us total":{
        "interaction rate":{
            total: total#,
            '%change': %change
        },
        "digital interaction rate":{
            total: total#,
            '%change': %change
        },
        "impressions":{
            total: total#,
            '%change': %change
        },
        "interactions":{
            total: total#,
            '%change': %change
        }
     },
     "discover me":{
        "digital u.s. discover site sessions":{
            total: total#,
            '%change': %change
        }
     },
     "me com":{
        "total me.com site sessions":{
            total: total#,
            '%change': %change
        }
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking to add. Please show an example of two (or more) objects you want to add and what the final output should look like.

Comment: Miles, please take a look at the jsfiddle. The example of two objects is the response data, final output is sumObj. I have included how it would look like. Also included in the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4z63cwhz/5/

Comment: You'll need to simplify your question to reduce the amount of time people need to spend on understanding your question. I suggest you remove all elements you don't want to add and update the sumObj with the actual results.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the json objects all repeat the same format then can't you just do:

```
var text= {};
local[current].attributeString (some calculation) local[next].attributeString += text;
```

where current = i and next = i+1.

Then you can use:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

to convert your String into a json object. I'd probably use some type of key/value pair instead of a string but this may help reduce some of your loops.